# Having an issue inserting a span tag into a div

Tags: javascript, html

So, Im currently taking classes to start a career in the coding industry, and Im stuck on this exercise:

Inside the div below, insert a span tag that has a class name of content and says "You got this!".

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Ive been at this for a couple days now, and this is the best attempt I think I've had so far.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'content';
var text = document.createTextNode("You got this!");
wrapper.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(span);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: wrapper.appendChild(text); -> span.appendChild(text);

Answer (score 3):

You needed to append the text to the span variable, not to "wrapper":

`span.appendChild(text);`

```js
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'content';
var text = document.createTextNode("You got this!");
span.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(span);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**Simpler answer :**

On a side note, you could also directly insert the text in the document without having to use a second variable like so :

```js
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'content';
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(span);
span.innerHTML = 'You got this!';
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3p98kbmo/)**.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you intended to write `span.appendChild(text);` instead of `wrapper.appendChild(text);`, because you want the TextNode to be appended to the span, not the wrapper.

If you encounter any problem or question while implementing my solution, please let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers cover much of it. I will cover adding `class="content"` to the `span`, which is also the part of this question.

We can use `setAttribute()` property to add any property on our HTML element.

So doing `span.setAttribute("class","content")` will set also set the `class="content"` for the span element. Below code will also work fine:

```js
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  let textnode = document.createTextNode("You got this!");
  span.setAttribute("class","content");
  span.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(span);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Is this better than using ```span.className = 'content';``` in any way?

Comment: Not much in this case! however, yes "It is better to get/set the className of an element using Element.getAttribute and Element.setAttribute if you are dealing with SVG elements." :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add text only one span that's class is content, I think you can do like this.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.classList.add("content");
var text = document.createTextNode("You got this!");
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
content.item(0).appendChild(text);
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(span);
```

Or if you don't need only that, you can do like this.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.classList.add("content");
var text = document.createTextNode("You got this!");
span.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(span);
```